# A question concerning Borel measurability and monotone functions

Tags: measure-theory

I came across the following exercise in my self-study:

If $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is monotone, then $f$ is Borel measurable.

I am unsure about how to proceed from the hypothesis to give the requisite proof, in particular how sensitive I should be to proof by cases. Would anyone visiting have any suggestions, or be up for proving this interesting little result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is Borel if and only if for all $a\in\mathbb R$, the set $\{x\in\mathbb R:f(x)>a\}$ is a Borel subset of $\mathbb R$.

Suggestion: Think about what possible types of sets you can get for $\{x\in\mathbb R:f(x)>a\}$ when $f$ is a monotone function.  You may want to conjecture with the aid of examples before trying to prove your conjecture.  The sets you get should be easily confirmed to be Borel.

Answer (score 6):

**Proposition**
Let $X$ be a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}$.
Let $\mathfrak{B}$ the set of Borel subsets of $X$.
$(X, \mathfrak{B})$ is a measurable space.
Let $f\colon X \rightarrow [-\infty, \infty]$ be a monotone function.
Then $f$ is measurable.

Proof:
Without loss of generality, we can assume that $f$ is non-decreasing.

Let $a \in (-\infty, \infty)$.
Let $E_a = \{x \in X; f(x) > a\}$.
Let $c = \inf E_a$.
It suffices to prove that $E_a$ is a Borel subset.

**Case 1**. $c \in E_a$.

Let $x \in X \cap [c, \infty)$
Since $c \le x$, $a < f(c) \le f(x)$.
Hence $x \in E_a$.

Conversely suppose $x \in E_a$.
Since $c \le x, x \in X \cap [c, \infty)$.

Therefore $E_a = X \cap [c, \infty)$.

**Case 2**. $c$ does not belong to $E_a$.

Let $x \in X \cap (c, \infty)$.
There exists $y \in E_a$ such that $c < y < x$.
Since $a < f(y) \le f(x), f(x) > a$.
Hence $x \in E_a$.

Conversely suppose $x \in E_a$.
Since $c \le x$ and $c$ does not belong to $E_a$, $x \in X \cap (c, \infty)$.

Therefore $E_a = X \cap (c, \infty)$.

**QED**