# Does monotonicity imply measurability?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be an increasing function. Prove or disprove: $f$ is Lebesgue measurable.

Thank you all for the great comments I'll receive! :D

Comment: Some related questions: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252421/are-monotone-functions-borel-measurable?rq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/105094/, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/229497/f-mathbfr-rightarrow-mathbfr-monotone-increasing-rightarrow-f-is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. It's a standard result that $f$ is measurable iff $f^{-1}([\alpha, \infty))$ is measurable for each $\alpha$, and such a pre-image must be either empty or an interval when  $f$ is monotone.

Comment: oh, it was very easy xD why didn't I see that!? thank you!